# How to make DHT22 shut up while I talk to another device on the same bus

Tags: microcontroller, avr, 1-wire

I have a project where multiple devices have to be connected to the same bus. One of them is a DHT22, another is another controller.

With the second controller I can communicate which ever way I want as far as timing goes, that doesn't really matter.

The first problem is the confusing info about the DHT22 in different sources. According to a Sparkfun pdf the reset pulse "must beyond at least 1ms". ocfreaks.com mentions 18ms.

In order not to trigger the DHT22 I decided to use 500us reset pulse when communicating with the second controller.

I find that the DHT22 still tries to send data and doing so ruins the communication. I have reduced the reset pulse between the 2 controller to 200us, then 100us, then finally to 50us, but the presence of the DHT22 still messes up the communication.

As part of another attempt I have tried to control the DHT22's VCC separately, but as it turns out when it's not powered it pulls the bus low. Quite a barbaric behaviour. If somebody has more experience taming the DHT22, please help.

PS: I don't know of any datasheet for the DHT22. There are some badly translated pdf documents around, but nothing decent with real info in it.

Edit: I didn't explain it well enough. I don't have any problems communicating with the DHT22. I want to communicate with another controller using the same bus and I need the DHT22 to stay quiet in order not to ruin the communications. My problem is that even though some datasheets say that the reset pulse should be at least 1ms, it responds to way shorter pulses as well, when it really shouldn't. I can't find an Aslong datasheet for the DHT22.

Comment: There are some references in my comments to the RpiSE Q&A. You might find them useful:https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133457/how-can-rpi4b-use-python-to-talk-to-the-i2c-dht20-sht20-temperature-and-humidi

Comment: (1)  I remember Aslong datasheets are the best. (2) Your comment about ***200uS*** reminds me that a couple of years ago, I tried to use MCP23017 to generate the 200uS and finally succeeded to talk to DHT22. References: (3) ***MCP23017 generating 200uS pulses for DHT22*** - 2018dec07rpi.forum.com
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1401437&hilit=DHT22+tlfong01#p1401437

(4) Search found 53 matches: DHT22 tlfong01 - forums.raspberrypi.com
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&keywords=DHT22+tlfong01&start=50

Comment: (5) There you are: my 200uS and the DHT22's response: https://imgur.com/gallery/TXN1GkR

Comment: (6) And the new generation ADHT20 uses serial I2C SCL and SDA signals, no more frightening 200uS pulse: https://www.adafruit.com/product/5183

Comment: Please specify what this "other controller" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpet the DHT22 protocol description correctly, communicating with another device on the same bus may not be possible.

You seem to expect that the pulse must be longer than 1ms before the sensor starts communicating, but that does not mean it will not respond to shorter pulses.

At least the protocol description never indicates that the low pulse length is validated by the sensor, so if the bus just happens to be low when sensor happens to check it, it may start communicating.

When the DHT22 is in sleep mode and waiting for the start pulse, the protocol documentation just requires that the start pulse must be more than 1ms for the DHT22 to detect it.

It may be because the DHT22 may wake up every 1ms to check if the data pin is low.

So it is possible that it can respond to any length low pulse if the bus is low when DHT22 checks it.

So it does not mean that the start pulse length itself is validated to be long enough to start communications, it just means the bus must be low when DHT22 checks the bus, and it checks it every 1ms to save power.

And turning off the power supply to a chip whose data pin needs to be high is an extremely bad idea in general. Normally I/O pins have protection diodes to VCC and GND, so basically by disconnecting the power supply, the chip will draw power from the supply via pull-up resistor and the protection diode of the data pin.

Comment: I don't get why turning a chip off is such a crazy thing to do. If there are many chips on a bus and one of them loses power then it should ruin the bus? A 24C32 with no VCC connected does not pull SDA low. Neither does a DS18B20 (I know, it's a different bus). It is important when a new device joins an existing bus. But thank you for thinking about how the DHT works! I wish it had proper documentation.

Comment: @GambanishuHabbeba I explained why a generic IO pin won't work and that is how most IO pins work, unless they are special. If you say that 24C32 works on bus without power then I believe you and it means it is special. Not all chips have IO protection diode to VCC if they are designed to be on a bus unpowered. Yes most of the time a single unpowered chip on a bus will make a bus fail. DS18B20 will suck parasite power from data pin by design.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the protection diodes. For example in the Atmel Attiny25... datasheet chapter 10.1 figure 10-1 on page 53: from the way the diodes are it looks like they would protect from voltages less than ground or more than vcc. Or at list I have always thought this is what protection diodes do. I would think that a tiny25 would not sink current on the IO pins when off. (Interestingly some of them actually do)

Comment: @GambanishuHabbeba Exactly,  diode protects from voltages more than VCC, by conducting from IO pin to VCC. If there is no VCC supply, VCC is 0V and the data pin and diode tries to push current into VCC. Any load on VCC, such as MCU itself, will consume current from VCC when it gets voltage from IO pin, which will load the IO pin voltage down.

Comment: I just wanted to say that VCC is not connected at all, then realized that the pin itself does not need to be connected, current will still flow through the diode, trying to raise VCC voltage, what the thing itself will happily use up. The only way to prevent the DHT sinking all the current from the bus, is to put more current on it than what the DHT needs. At which point the DHT is actually turned on. :( I use a separate bus for the DHT now and my gadget works fine. Thanks for your input!